# Double presentation and precision?

Tags: c#, c++, double, precision

I've written following code in c++ :

```
double t = pow(pow(2, 32), 4)+5;
double div = floor(t / pow(2, 32));
double div2 = div*pow(2, 32);
double remain = t - div2;
cout << remain << endl;
```

the remain must be 5 but console and debugging show me 0.00000000 ??? why?

similar code in c#:

```
double t = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(2, 32), 4) + 5;
double div = Math.Floor(t / Math.Pow(2, 32));
double div2 = div * Math.Pow(2, 32);
double remain = t - div2;
Console.WriteLine(remain);
```

Comment: Because of integer division maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding *5* to *2<sup>128</sup>* using `double`. For the addition of *5* to have any effect it would need to use, at least, 127 bits to represent the significant. It uses 52 if I recall correctly. You'd need to use a much bigger representation. Since you only do integer operations a big integer representation should do.

Answer (score 1):

Your function overflows... Use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)...

```
var t = BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger.Pow(2, 32), 4) + 5;
var div = t / BigInteger.Pow(2, 32);
var div2 = div * BigInteger.Pow(2, 32);
var remain = t - div2;
Console.WriteLine(remain);
```